# django many to many get attributes from other object

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, many-to-many

So I've been using django for a while now, and it's great. I've recently come across a little bit of a problem, and I'm sure there's a crappy way to get it to work, but what I've found with Django is that they've usually built in all sorts of mechanisms to do things for you. So what I'm not finding is this:

Here are my models:

```
class LandmarkGroup(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    IsActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    landmarks = models.ManyToManyField('Landmark', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.Name

class Landmark(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    Polygon = models.PolygonField()
    IsActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.Name
```

I also have another model 'Team' that has a ManyToMany with LandmarkGroup, but I'm not going to post it here. I have a view where I query for all the landmarks that have a landmarkgroup that has a team with the same team id as the one I passed in:

```
def mobile_startup(request):
...
    landmarkGroups = LandmarkGroup.objects.filter(team=device.team, IsActive=True)
    landmarks = Landmark.objects.filter(landmarkgroup__team=device.team, IsActive=True)
...
return render_to_response('webservice/mobile_startup.html', {'landmarks': landmarks, 'landmarkGroups': landmarkGroups})
```

Everything works, the only problem I'm having is, I'm returning this all as JSON to the mobile app, and I want to provide the landmarkGroup id for the landmark, so in my template I've been trying to:

```
"landmarkGroup" : {{ landmark.landmarkgroup.id }} }
```

but that's not working. Does anyone know any way I can get the landmarkGroup ID for each landmark in my set? Do I need to extract it when I do the query? I know I can reference each landmarkGroup in the query because I can do 'landmarkgroup__team=device.team', but I need to able to reference this object in the template

Answer (score 0):

`LandmarkGroup.landmarks`is a `ManyToManyField`,therefore one `Landmark` can belong to *multiple* groups.

You should be able to output them in your template like this:

```
{% for group in landmark.landmarkgroup_set.all %}{{ group.pk }}{% endfor %}
```

The first group belonging to the landmark should be accessible through `{% landmark.landmarkgroup_set.all.0 %}`

Comment: Yeah, I've read that, but I figured since I could do `Landmark.objects.filter(landmarkgroup__team=device.team, IsActive=True)` I should be able to get that landmarkgroup or at least the id at the same time.

Comment: @Josh: Well you can do that at the same time, but still _more than one_ landmarkgroup can belong to a landmark due to your model setup. If you want to avoid that you should use a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: No, I want that. I actually used to have it set up the other way (one to many between landmarkgroup and landmark), but I went this way so a user wouldnt have to recreate a landmark everytime they wanted to add it to a group. Do you know how to select the id at the same time I make that query above? And then how to reference that id? The best answer I've found is define my own intermediate table and query that one instead of the landmarks table

Comment: @Josh: If you want to do it in one db query using an intermediate table for the many-to-many relation is for sure the way to go, as you can select its data using [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) in one query. (If you want somehow the same functionality for many-to-many and are willing to update your Django, Django 1.4rc1 offers you [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Comment: So it seems the downside to this approach is I can't use `filter_horizontal` in the admin form anymore correct?

Comment: @Josh: You can use an InlineAdmin to edit the information stored in the intermediate model!

Comment: Yes, but I don't think I can manipulate it so that I can use filter_horizontal since it's not technically a m2m anywhere